SQLException with #now()#
We are attempting to build a backup server for a legacy CF10 application - "just in case", whilst rebuilding the application - properly!
"Everything" is the same as far as we can tell:

MS SQL 2014 12.0.6179.1 (compatibility SQL Server 2008)
ColdFusion 10,284825
ODBC "SQL Server" drive: 10.00.14393.7155 (not sure this matters)
Windows Server 2016 (CF admin settings summary has this in both cases down as Windows Server 2012)
ODBC drivers "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server", "SQL Server" and "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" are the same on both

We have one problem - now() is not working correctly. This works on the production server but fails on the new:
INSERT INTO User_Log VALUES ('test', 'None', 'Log In', 'The user logged in', #now()#)
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"
This is NOT a good way of doing things, but this is a legacy application and now() is used A LOT! So hopefully there's a platform setting.......
This SQL statement executes within Management Studio AND within cfquery:
INSERT INTO User_Log VALUES ('test', 'None', 'Log In', 'The user logged in', {ts '2024-07-23 16:44:11'})
They should be identical - i.e. this INSERT statement is exactly what was shown in the SQLDataException.
Any suggestions?

Why don't you simply use the now() function of SQL?

You can use getDate() - sql function directly in there.
